# Filter array result with mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

I'm getting images from a url with Mechanize with this code!

```
url = "http://cnn.com"
page = Mechanize.new.get(url)
images = page.images.map{|img| img.url.to_s}
```

**I want to get only, the images that have a minimum width and height.**

e.g. I want get only images with height minimum **100px** and width minimum **100px**.

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use ImageMagick to check size image

Comment: I need use methods **width** and **height** from Mechanize. I can not use ImageMagick for this objetive.

Comment: I went through `Mechanize` code and I'm sure you are not able to get image size using `Mechanize`

Comment: The fix for this problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445787/get-values-from-ruby-array-if-condition/9445802