# get values from ruby array if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm mapping a array with this code:

```
url = "http://www.cnn.com"
page = Mechanize.new.get(url)
images_url = page.images.map{|img| img.url.to_s if (img.width.to_i > 200)}
```

I get this result in console:

```
[nil, "http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/110929092349-nelson-mandela-t1-main.jpg", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120225123812-syria-mani-2-c1-main.jpg", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120225022127-blue-fish-bin-tease.jpg", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

I want get this array without **nil** values, its mean, I want get a array sth like:

```
["http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/110929092349-nelson-mandela-t1-main.jpg", "http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120225123812-syria-mani-2-c1-main.jpg", "http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120225022127-blue-fish-bin-tease.jpg"]
```

**For this case, 3 values.**

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the `compact` method on your Array to remove empty results from it.

```
images_url = page.images.map{|img| img.url.to_s if (img.width.to_i > 200)}.compact
```

Comment: Thank you Matteo could you put the example for this case?. Thank you!

Comment: sure, I've just added it to the answer

Comment: `images_url = page.images.map{|img| img.url.to_s if (img.width.to_i > 200)}.compact!`

Comment: @hyperrjas You don't want `compact!`. If there are no `nil` values in the array, `compact!` will return `nil` instead of the list of URLs. You probably want `compact` (i.e. without the `!`, as in Matteo's example).

Comment: nice. i have been using <code>reject{|i| i.nil?}</code> till now

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Array#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete) if you ever want to remove things other than `nil`, without modifying the receiver (add an bang [`!`] if you want do want it to.

Or if you want to delete elements based on something other than if it matches, you can use [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete_if). It iterates over each element with a block you provide and removes the element if the return value of that block evaluates to `true`.

Here are some examples of both:

```
    ary = [42, nil, "foo", "bar", "foo", Object.new, self, /hi/]
    ary.delete("foo")  #=> [42, nil, 'bar', #<Object:xxxxx&rt, main, /hi/]
    ary                #=> [42, nil, "foo", "bar", "foo", Object.new, self, /hi/]
    ary.delete_if {|elem|
      elem.class == Object or
      elem.kind_of?(Regexp)
    }                  #=> [42, nil, "foo", "bar", "foo"]
```

Hope this helps! :)